When are too many questions in a single post too many questions?
Working through the close votes review queue, I just failed an audit for the question Lie group cohomology: a jungle of conditions, which I voted to close as In need of Focus whereas apparently the correct thing to do would have been to vote to leave open.
This leaves me somewhat puzzled. After all, the post in question asks, in order:

"Similarly, we look for central extensions of $G$ by $A$, where $A$ is an abelian topological group. What classifies these?"
"Moreover, in the case of $H^2_{\mathrm{meas}}(G, A)$, what are the $σ$ algebras with respect to which measurability is imposed?"
"Which classifies Lie group extensions of $G$ by $A$, where $A$ is assumed to be an abelian Lie group out of these two? Are there other definitions of Lie group cohomology? Which definition classifies precisely what?"
"Another important question: for Lie groups $G$, does any of the two definitions above relate to singular or deRham cohomology?"
"Last, but not least, is there a possibility of extending these definitions (all of them, or any of them) to the case where $A$ is not abelian?"

At the risk of stating the obvious, that's more than one question, even if generously interpreted.
Now, the post in question is also rather well received; at the time of writing, it has 7 upvotes and an accepted answer (and I agree that the question is good, besides this issue). I would then like to ask what the correct stance / course of action here is: Am I missing something? Does the popularity of the question override concerns about site policy?
(Note that my concern here is not with "how to avoid failing audits like this" but rather with how to behave around questions like this in general.)

You're right, it should have been closed as needing focus. There's no reason the five questions cannot and should not be asked separately.

This makes me curious about how these audits are designed. This example makes it seem like they are designed automatically based on vote totals. I wonder if stackexchange has a method of detecting "bad audits" by noticing a high rate of audit failure! I would have failed it too.

I agree with you.  I would have voted in the same way.  That sounds like it was a bad audit.  Unfortunately, bad audits are a fact of life (sigh).
The usual rule on Stack Exchange is "one question per post".
There are several reasons for this rule.  We want to build an archive of knowledge that will contribute to knowledge on the Internet, in the form of questions and answers.  We also want to keep a reasonable load on answerers, so we need questions to be reasonably scoped; as a rough rule of thumb, in most cases we hope questions can be answered in a few paragraphs.  When a post contains multiple questions, it's often asking too much of answerers.  Also, our experience suggests that it can lead to bad results when there are multiple questions per post.  Perhaps someone writes an answer that answers some of the questions but not others, and that answer is upvoted and accepted.  Now the question is treated by our system as answered (e.g., for purposes of search), even though some of the questions haven't been answered (making it harder for those who search for unanswered questions to find).  Also, what if someone else is also wondering about one of those questions, finds the page on this site by Internet search, and then discovers that the one of the questions they had wasn't answered by any of the answers?  That's a lousy experience.
See Can I ask only one question per post? and Multi-Question Questions: How Best to Handle Them? for more details and reasoning.
That said, the close vote queue is managed by the community -- i.e., by people.  It reflects the opinion of people who participate in reviewing questions in the queue.  Sometimes people have different values or opinions.  I have shared my opinion, but others here might well have a different view about what is best for the site, and vote accordingly.  And sometimes people make mistakes or are unaware of site guidelines.

I agree with this answer.  I would (very rarely) consider as exceptional, a post with two questions rather than one, where the questions are very closely related, and where the methods use to solve one of the questions also applies to the other question.  Here, I might also be influenced by whether there is some direct contrast between the two questions that causes the problem solver to have their intuition expanded by considering the questions in tandem.

Important to note that both of the links you provided say you can ask multiple closely related questions in the same post. What's not allowed is to ask multiple unrelated questions in the same post. The linked question has several very closely related subquestions, which is not actually against the policy at all.

Although I've no expertise in the topic, the question looks to me as if it can be summarised as "here is a thing I understand in the finite dimensional case, and my question is how it extends to the general case. Here is a list of specific things that I don't find obvious, which I hope a good answer would resolve."
It is perhaps unfortunate for the OP that they decided to delimit this list with question marks rather than bullet points or semicolons etc., but that doesn't really change the fact that it's ultimately one question. Although I could be wrong, it feels to me that attempting to split it into multiple questions would just be busy work, resulting in a bunch of less clear questions whose answers wouldn't be as helpful.
Note that both the SE guidelines and the math.SE ones say quite explicitly that you can have closely related sub-questions in the same post. They prohibit multiple unrelated questions in the same post, but sufficiently closely related sub-questions have never been against policy.
It would be unproductive to turn a good principle (one question per post) into a bureaucratic box ticking rule (one question mark per post). Most users can't possibly know about such a one question mark rule - especially since it's not even official policy - and it leads otherwise good questions to be closed for no reason. I think we should regard it as incumbent on close voters to apply the rules in a principled way, and not on question askers to spend hours reading meta before they post anything.

Given the general Stackexchange guidelines and our site guidelines on this issue, I would think that it is the OP's job to check whether they are separate questions or just sub-questions of the main one, and then: if the latter, re-write the question with much more clarity regarding the issue; if the former ask separate questions, of course.

@LeeMosher your comment misses the main point of my post, which is that multiple questions $\ne$ multiple question marks. You have to do the work to figure out which one it is, rather than take the lazy shortcut of equating them.

I think I do understand your post. My point is that I, the reader of the post, should not have to do the work that you are talking about, instead it is the OP's job to do that work during the act of composing their post. If the OP has not done that job, then the question should be closed.

I don't think this is an issue of bureacratic box ticking. I have generally found that when a post contains multiple questions, and when a user (like me) leaves a comment on the order of "please ask one question per post", together with a link to our policy, the OP generally responds well by editing their question to comply with that policy, and there is a good outcome: the question is improved, and it attracts good answers (hopefully).

The particular post under discussion in this thread is rather exceptional, in that it got a good answer before anyone had the opportunity to leave a "please ask one question per post" comment. But I don't think that suggests there is anything at all wrong with the policy.

@LeeMosher I also think the policy is good, but the policy is one question per post and not one question mark per post. Or more precisely, the policy is "don't ask two independent questions in the same post" and not "don't ask a question that has sub-questions." The latter would be a bad policy. I also sometimes edit questions to remove extra question marks or ask the OP to do so, but only because I'm afraid other people will follow the bad misinterpretation of the policy and close the question even though there's fundamentally nothing wrong with it.

Note that I'm not making this up. Of the two links you provided, the first is about asking two separate questions that have nothing in common besides the tags, while the second explicitly allows for closely related subquestions.

Completely agree with this answer. Too often I see "one question per post" comments by people who haven't read or understood the question, but are just counting the number of question marks as you say. Splitting the linked question into five (!) different questions (as suggested in another comment) would be ridiculous..
